# Asymptotic approximations for $\binom NK$ for comparing with $K^K \log(K)$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Is there any approximations available for $\large\binom N K$ suitable for comparing with $K^K \log K$ ?
What is the threshold that reverses the inequality sign?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have another condition? $1^1 \log 1 < \binom{9}{1}$ and $\binom{9}{4} < 4^4 \log 4$

Comment: Mahdi, please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: If it depends on $K$, then how the problem varies with respect to $K$? I want to compare them by orders of magnitude not to just say which one is greater!

Comment: I don't see how, even if $K > 5$. Take $\binom{100}{6} > 6^6 \log 6$ and $\binom{100}{49} < 49^{49} \log 49$.

Comment: Pretty clearly, for any $k>0$ there exists an $n$ such that $\binom{n}{k}>k^k\log k$

Comment: Conversely, the central binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$ is less than $4^n$ for $n \geq 1$, while $k^k$ can be as large as $n^n$.

Comment: Is there any approximations available for $\large\binom N K$ Suitable to compare with $K^K \log K$ ?

Comment: There's $(\frac{n}{k})^k < \binom{n}{k} < (\frac{en}{k})^k$

Comment: @Mahdi: A key difference between the expressions is that one depends on $N$ and the other doesn't. You should expect different results, e.g., using ${{2K+1}\choose K}$ vs. ${{K^2}\choose K}$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro If it was an approximation it would be useful.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I know, I'm looking for the thresholds that reverses the inequality sign!

Comment: @Mahdi: Thank you. I did not understand that from what was posted.

Comment: Using Michael's inequalities, set $n = k^2 (\log k)^{1/k}$ to get $k^k \log k \leq {n \choose k} \leq e^k k^k \log k$. Also notice for $n = k^2$, we have ${n \choose k} \leq e^k k^k = o(k^k \log k)$.